# Windows server 2008 fails to respond to SYN sometimes

Tags: windows

I have a problem seen on Windows Server 2008 running IIS 7. I have seen a packet trace where the server stops responding to SYN from clients. However, it will respond to intermediate SYNs i.e

```
Say Client A sends SYN 1 at time t1.
Server will not respond
Client A now sends SYN 2 for a *different* connection at time t2 (t2 > t1)
Server responds.
Client A retransmits SYN 1 . 
Server fails to respond
```

Ultimately client A times out. How do I find the reason why server is not responding to one particular connection.

Are there TCP stats that one can see on the Windows Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to packet sniff on both sides of the connection.  You may see the SYN being sent, but maybe it never actually reaches its destination.  Something filtering?